# Park Break Cable Sensor

Tags: electric-vehicle, handbrake, parking-brake, break

We are developing an autonomous vehicle as a university project. And we want to know if the parking brake cable is broken. I searched this on the internet. But I didn't find anything. Is there a special sensor that can detect it or how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the parking brake actuator is not in the "open" position - a micro switch will do that.

Comment: Thanks this gave us ideas. But we need something safer.

Comment: "Safer" what do you mean? Checking the actual lever that actuates the parking brake is as close as you get...

Comment: i mean, we want something that doesn't deteriorate for too long and that's resistant to vibration.

Comment: @umuryasinalper - I'm not sure how a micro-switch doesn't fullfil that mission? They are used all the time where vibration is present (all over non-autonomous vehicles) and they are quite resilliant, lasting many years if not the complete life of the vehicle.

Comment: @umuryasinalper Then use an magnetic sensor onto the lever instead of a  microswitch. Compare that with the position of the handbrake